# SQL Convert varchar to datetime is only

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a query from which I want to convert a varchar to a datetime, and I am getting a result I can not understand.
For example: I have a varchar field (cAnmerkung) in which I am extracting the german date 12.02.2019 with charindex() and substring(). This is necessary because the date in the varchar is after a specific text ('HereItIs: 12.02.2019') Then I change this date to be able to convert it to datetime with replace(). Finally the convert() to datetime is working:

```
select a.cArtNr, SUBSTRING(b.cAnmerkung, CHARINDEX('HereItIs',b.cAnmerkung)+13 , 10) as 'GermanDate'
, replace(SUBSTRING(b.cAnmerkung, CHARINDEX('HereItIs',b.cAnmerkung)+13 , 10), '.', '/') as 'testFormat'
, convert(datetime, replace(SUBSTRING(b.cAnmerkung, CHARINDEX('HereItIs',b.cAnmerkung)+13 , 10), '.', '/'), 103) as 'ConvertedDate'
from tOrder b 
join tPosition p on p.tBestellung_kBestellung = b.kBestellung 
join tArticel a on a.kArtikel = p.tArtikel_kArtikel 
join tStock l on l.kArtikel = a.kArtikel
where b.cAnmerkung LIKE '%HereItIs%' 
and l.fLagerbestandEigen > 0
and SUBSTRING(b.cAnmerkung, CHARINDEX('HereItIs',b.cAnmerkung)+13 , 10) NOT LIKE '[A-Za-z]%'
```

This query is working. I get this result:
[image: resultExample]

My problem is now, that I need to remove the column 'testFormat'. But as soon as I remove this part of the query:

```
, replace(SUBSTRING(b.cAnmerkung, CHARINDEX('HereItIs',b.cAnmerkung)+13 , 10), '.', '/') as testFormat
```

I am getting the error:

> "Error converting a string to a date and/or time."

Does someone know why the same query does only convert the varchar to datetime when I have the replace() in the select()?

Comment: You probably have some data which cannot be cast. sometimes sql server chooses different path which materializes that select and then it fails. You can replace convert with TRY_CONVERT so it fails on failure

Comment: I would suggest the real question is why are you storing date (and time) data as a `varchar` in the first place? If you use an actual date and time data type you *can't* store an invalid date. You should really be looking to fix your design.

Comment: @siggemannen thanks! try_convert() is working. I do not know why I did not think of this. I am still puzzled by the result. With the replace() and convert() in place I get 1855 rows. And when I remove the replace() and use try_convert() I still get 1855 rows. So it looks to me, as there is no data which can not be converted. Can I mark a comment as the solution?

Comment: @ThomA The date is just an input from the user in the comment field. I just want to extract that handmade date and use it. In our program I can not put a new field, so the users can add these dates to be stored in a proper way. This is not my design and I am not able to change it. Sry.

Comment: yes, but perhaps sql server traverses different number of other rows depending on the query you're running.